# Socrata API deep scrolling in R

Tags: r, pagination, rate-limiting, socrata

**Edit** My question has changed considerably as I learned more about the problem. After adding several edits this post became unwieldy, so I'm starting over with a clean slate and the final question.

I'm trying to download all public datasets for the state of Utah through the [state Socrata portal](https://opendata.utah.gov/) using R. There are more than 10,000 records listed, so [deep scrolling](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/other/discovery.html#?route=get-/catalog/v1) methods using the `scroll_id` parameter are required. Using this parameter in the query returns results alphabetically by `resource.id`. However, using a NULL id defaults to starting with the first *letter* alphabetically and will not return all results because several thousand records begin with a number.

My question is: how can I query with the `scroll_id` parameter such that it starts with the record with the lowest number, rather than first letter?

The workaround I have is first querying the portal without a `scroll_id` parameter. This will return 10,000 results in arbitrary order. I then take the lowest digit record from that set and re-query with deep scrolling from there. This produces what I imagine is *most* records, but probably not all. I'm sure this is an absurd workaround for a simple problem, but here is the code I'm working with:

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse,
               httr,
               jsonlite)

# Function to query without scroll_id
get_socrata_data <- function(domain, 
                             limit = 15000) {
    "http://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?domains=${domain}&limit=${limit}" %>%
        str_interp() %>%
        httr::GET() %>%
        content("text") %>%
        fromJSON(flatten = TRUE)
}

# Scroll function that includes scroll_id
scroll_socrata <- function(domain,
                           limit = 15000,
                           scroll_id = NULL) {
    "http://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?domains=${domain}&scroll_id=${scroll_id}&limit=${limit}" %>%
        str_interp() %>%
        httr::GET() %>%
        content("text") %>%
        fromJSON(flatten = TRUE)
}

ut_domain <- 'opendata.utah.gov'

# Initial query without scroll_id
ut_results <- get_socrata_data(ut_domain)
nrow(ut_results$results)

# If results are capped, restart with first digit id using scroll function
if (nrow(ut_results$results) == 10000) {
    
    # Pull out first record starting with digit
    digit_start <- ut_results$results |>
        filter(str_starts(resource.id, '\\d'))
    first_digit_id <- first(sort(digit_start$resource.id))
    
    # Data frame for results
    output <- data.frame()
    
    # Restart query with scroll_socrata function that includes scroll_id
    page <- scroll_socrata(ut_domain,
                           scroll_id = first_digit_id)
    
    output <- bind_rows(output, page$results)
    
    # more pages if necessary
    while (nrow(page$results) == 10000) {
        page <- scroll_socrata(ut_domain,
                               scroll_id = last(page$results$resource.id))
        output <- bind_rows(output, page$results)
    }
}

# check total
nrow(output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At long last, the very simple answer to my problem. Entering a scroll_id of '0' will query records starting with the resource.id with the lowest digit.

```
scroll_socrata <- function(domain,
                           limit = 15000,
                           scroll_id = NULL) {
    "http://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?domains=${domain}&scroll_id=${scroll_id}&limit=${limit}" %>%
        str_interp() %>%
        httr::GET() %>%
        content("text") %>%
        fromJSON(flatten = TRUE)
}

ut_domain <- 'opendata.utah.gov'

# DF for results
output <- data.frame()

# First query starting with lowest digit resource.id
page <- scroll_socrata(ut_domain, 
                       limit = 15000,
                       scroll_id = '0')

output <- bind_rows(output, page$results)

# More pages if necessary
while (nrow(page$results) == 10000) {
    page <- scroll_socrata(ut_domain,
                           limit = 15000,
                           scroll_id = last(page$results$resource.id))
    output <- bind_rows(output, page$results)
}
    
output
```